# using mediaPlayer in java class and calling it on mainActivity android

Tags: java, android, crash, android-mediaplayer

Ive tried to use MediaPlayer in a class and call that class on MainActivity but the app keeps on crashing. I tried searching and Couldn't find a way to do this. any ideas?

```
public class TestMedia extends MainActivity {

public void Test01(){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.one);

    mediaPlayer0.start();
}
```

}

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TestMedia test02 = new TestMedia();
    test02.Test01();}
```

Comment: What crash message do you get? (Check logcat)

Answer (score 0):

The code segment provided is strange, why are you instantiating "TestMedia" in "onCreate()" of "TestMedia"?

Activity class aren't supposed to be instantiated like this.

Try to replace

```
    TestMedia test02 = new TestMedia(); 
    test02.Test01();
```

with

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.one);                      
    mediaPlayer0.start();
```

Comment: its in a diffrent class. dont I need to do this (the test isnt in mainactivity)?

Comment: Activity class aren't supposed to be instantiated like this.

Try to replace 

        TestMedia test02 = new TestMedia();
        test02.Test01();

with 

         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.one);

        mediaPlayer0.start();